# Connection time out installing mysql server in unix

Tags: mysql, unix, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am trying to install mysql server in my AWS EC2 instance. I googled and executed the below command in the shell.

```
 sudo yum install mysql-server
```

It throws the below connection timed out exception

```
Loaded plugins: priorities, update-motd, upgrade-helper
http://packages.us-west- 2.amazonaws.com/2014.03/main/201403504e47/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml?instance_id=i-c82c93c3&region=us-west-2: [Errno 12] Timeout on http://packages.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/2014.03/main/201403504e47/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml?instance_id=i-c82c93c3&region=us-west-2: (28, 'Connection timed out after 10001 milliseconds')
Trying other mirror.
```

Is this the right way to install mysql server?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### installing mysql

From the current [AWS EC2 documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/install-LAMP.html):

> To install and start the LAMP web server
>
> Connect to your instance.
>
> To ensure that all of your software packages are up to date, perform a quick software update on your instance. This process may take a few minutes, but it is important to make sure you have the latest security updates and bug fixes.
>
> Note
>   The -y option installs the updates without asking for confirmation. If you would like to examine the updates before installing, you can omit this option.

```
[ec2-user ~]$ sudo yum update -y
```

> Now that your instance is current, you can install the Apache web server, MySQL, and PHP software packages. Use the yum groupinstall command to install multiple software packages and all related dependencies at the same time.

```
[ec2-user ~]$ sudo yum groupinstall -y "Web Server" "MySQL Database" "PHP Support"
```

> Note
>   Non-Amazon Linux instances may have subtle differences in their group names. If the above command fails because of an invalid group name, use the yum grouplist command and scan the output for similar groups, such as "MySQL Database server" instead of "MySQL Database", and use the appropriate group name for your distribution.
>
> Install the php-mysql package.

```
[ec2-user ~]$ sudo yum install -y php-mysql
```

I suppose you only need to install mysql, so you just need to run the 1st command, adapt the second to only grab mysql from the repositories, and skip the last one:

```
[ec2-user ~]$ sudo yum update -y

[ec2-user ~]$ sudo yum groupinstall -y "MySQL Database"
```

Depending on which version of linux you have installed (Amazon, Red Hat or CentOS), you may need to change the string `"MySQL Database"` to something else. The following command:

```
[ec2-user ~]$ sudo yum grouplist
```

Will list all the possible group install you may perform, so you need to filter it to get the right string:

```
[ec2-user ~]$ sudo yum grouplist | grep -i mysql
```

And choose the most appropriate one in that filtered result set.

#### network connectivity

Now, regarding your specific issue, the [FAQs](http://aws.amazon.com/amazon-linux-ami/faqs/#auto_update) describes your problem as follow:

> If the AMI cannot access the yum repositories, it will timeout and retry multiple times before completing the boot procedure. Possible reasons for this are restrictive firewall settings or VPC settings, which prevent access to the Amazon Linux AMI package repositories.
>
> If you encounter this issue you can either modify your environment so that the Amazon Linux AMI can connect to its package repositories [...]

Unfortunately, no explanations are given as yo how you can change your environment to enable connectivity.

Apparently, by using the dashboard, you should be able to open outbound access to the port the yum servers are using:

```
AWS dashboard > ec2 > security groups > default group > outbound rule: ??? (HTTP*) 0.0.0.0/???
```

The usual port for yum server is 80, so just replace `???` above by 80 to have access to the repos. You also should replace `0.0.0.0` with the actual repository server address.

If this solution does not work, you might also try disabling the firewall altogether for the duration of the update:

```
[ec2-user ~]$ sudo /etc/init.d/iptables stop

<...Update commands as listed above...>

[ec2-user ~]$ sudo /etc/init.d/iptables start
```

Or

```
[ec2-user ~]$ sudo /sbin/service iptables stop

<...>

[ec2-user ~]$ sudo /sbin/service iptables start
```

Comment: I tried "sudo yum update -y", end result is same. Connection timed out.

Answer (score 0):

I just delete all the files in /etc/resolv.conf dir